# Reduce reputation gain from associating account(s)

Tags: discussion, reputation, association, linked-accounts

I love it when it happens to me, but +100 for a n00b like me is counter-productive. I'd say at most +50, and phase out when you have >5 accounts (maybe that's already the case?).

Comment: What problem does this solve?

Comment: Reputation is sacred here. I shouldn't get so much for doing nothing.

Comment: The idea is that once you have gained 200 rep on a site, you shouldn't be treated as a complete newbie on the other sites.

Comment: Re 2nd comment from @jinguy: that's a good point, but then I shouldn't get 100 on BOTH sites.

Comment: @Geo You mean the site you had 200 on and the new site? You don't, you only get the +100 bonus on the new account side. It's for the reason jjnguy said; you can probably be trusted with the <=100 rep stuff if you've gotten to 200 rep on at least one SE site

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: IIRC you do get 100 rep on the source site the first time you do it. That's probably for historical reasons from when it was just an incentive to associate accounts.

Comment: If you're desperate to earn all your rep on each new site you register at you could always add bounty of 100 rep to a question you like upon joining.

Comment: @Simon Oh, you're right; my mistake. It's important that it only happens once though, you can't associate with SOFU and every SE beta and get 3000 rep out of it

Comment: Sorry I hallucinated about seeing +100 on SO. I did gain some points that pushed me over from 500 to 600. I guess I'm too hung up on rep, an early and sure sign of SoAS (SO Addiction Syndrome).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

100 rep isn't that much and gives you enough to:

- Edit community wiki posts
- Upvote and downvote (and only twice without getting more rep)
- Leave comments
- Flag posts

To me these seem like things that don't cause much damage and someone who is relatively trustworthy and knows the system (from their other account with 200+) should be able to do. I think it would also be frustrating and off-putting for someone who already knows the system to not be able to do these things. They're also less likely to be a sockpuppet.

On the other hand, someone new to the system needs to understand how it works before being able to do these thing and won't be as frustrated by not being able to as they (unless their rep is between 100 and 200) never could.

Comment: Gosh I didn't even know those. I haven't felt frustrated at all by my gutter-bottom rep here since that's what I deserve, and I would work hard to earn the rep instead of just registering on other SE sites. Hmmm maybe that's what I should do now.

Comment: @Geoffrey Zheng: Including them in my post makes it more obvious what I'm referring to. Also, what damage does it do not to have these from the outset?

Comment: is that a question for me? I think you can leave comments from the outset, no?

Comment: @Geoffrey Zheng: Only on meta, your own questions/answers, and private beta sites.