# Dynamic calculation of reputation based on voter's rank

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Indicate How Trustworthy the UpVotes Are](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22151/indicate-how-trustworthy-the-upvotes-are)

When calculating score for up vote/down vote should the rank of person issuing the vote be taken into account?

Say if your question has been up voted by a person with higher score, you get more points, and vice versa.

Please find flaws.

Comment: The first flaw I see, is that it was already suggested

Comment: could you mark as duplicate then?

Comment: I know this has been suggested before, but I wasn't able to find a duplicate to link. It seems to be a hard topic to search...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22151/indicate-how-trustworthy-the-upvotes-are

Comment: Yey, someone found our dupe.

Comment: @random: bah. I was looking forward to reading the original so I could down-vote that as well... only to find it locked. Now I feel cheated.

Answer (score 2):

No, leave it as it is. It's a **democracy**, everyone gets equal voting rights, otherwise the playing field will not be even.

That's the great thing about Stack Overflow, all votes are the same, no matter who casts them. Also, this could be a **privacy concern** because if I see a +/- 25 I'll know it was from a high rep user; if that person also left a comment or answer, it could confirm my suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

We have just gone through a tumultuous upheaval. And now, we'd like to somehow go back and figure out a weighted calculation of up-votes & down-votes based on the voter's reputation? No...here's one reason I can think of:

Voting on questions should not be weighted by the voter's reputation for the simple fact that a question is **not** the reason we are here. We are here to get answers. A good question is rewarded with up-votes. Answers are what we want - good answers are what we want to reward. I think that the current system for points awarded is excellent and see no reason whatsoever to change it...yet.